# Vuetify search-input.sync for v-autocomplete inside v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-composition-api, v-autocomplete

I have a `line_items` array, iterated using `v-for`. For each of the `line_item` object, I need a `v-autocomplete` element that is used to search for `category`.

Currently, I'm using the `search-input.sync="searchText"` to do sync search as the user types into the text input box. This works well if there is a single `line_item` object, but if there are 2 or more, the `searchText` change affects all other `line_items` too.

Example code:

```
<div v-for="line_item in line_items">
  <v-autocomplete
    :items=""categories
    :search-input.sync="searchText"
    placeholder="Select category"
  ></v-autocomplete>
</div>
```

And I'm using the `watch` method from the composition API to watch for changes in `searchText` like so:

```
const searchText = ref(null)
watch(searchText, query => fetchCategories(query))
```

How do I go about correcting this problem? If possible, I'd really like to keep the `.sync` behavior so that the search function fires off whenever user inputs something. TIA!

Comment: can you provide some links to the code means replica of your code so I can understand more about your query ?

Comment: Did you found any solution for this?

Comment: @JuanCarlosAlfonsoVergel nope, I ended up just passing an unpaginated list to the autocomplete field. Will probably have to revisit this in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Fahmiin I create a custom component to create  rows with autocomplete inside, like:

```
      <QuickOrderForm
        v-bind:key="index"
        :productIndex="index"
        :item="item"
        :productOptions="productOptions"
        :optionSelected="optionSelected"
        :priceFormat="priceFormat"
        @update-order-data="productOptionSelected"
      />
```

And `QuickOrderForm` has like this:

```
template>
  <v-row class="rowMain">
    <v-autocomplete
      v-model="itemSku"
      :loading="loading"
      :items="resultSearchItem"
      :search-input.sync="search"
      @focus="resultSearchItem = []"
      hide-selected
      class="mx-4"
      hide-no-data
      hide-details
      outlined
      placeholder="Enter Product SKU"
    ></v-autocomplete>
    <v-text-field
      v-model="qty"
      placeholder="Qty #"
      :disabled="itemSku === '' ? true : false"
      outlined
      type="number"
    ></v-text-field>
    <v-text-field
      prefix="$"
      v-model="priceFormat"
      outlined
      disabled
    ></v-text-field>
  </v-row>
</template>
```